# Problem in simulation with BGP configuration

Tags: omnet++

I would like to create a simple topology in Omnet 6.0.1,  with 3 BGP routers and 3 Ipv6 border routers, but  I got the below error, and I am not able to figure out why I'm getting this error:

> <!> BGP Error:  No AS configuration for Router ID: 10.0.0.9 -- in module (inet::bgp::Bgp) MyNetwork_1.A.bgp (id=77), during network initialization

I don't recognize this address router that I didn't configure in my BGP configuration?
Please, Can anyone please tell me, what is the problem?
I sincerely appreciate you helping me; thank you very much.

XML Configuration:

```
<BGPConfig >
    <TimerParams>
        <connectRetryTime> 120 </connectRetryTime>
        <holdTime> 180 </holdTime>
        <keepAliveTime> 60 </keepAliveTime>
        <startDelay> 15 </startDelay>
    </TimerParams> 

    <Devices>
        <Router name="A" id="100.0.1.1" >
            <Interfaces>
                <Interface id="eth0">
                    <Ipv4 address="10.0.13.1" netmask="255.255.255.252" />
                    <Ipv6 address="fd00:13:13::0/127" />
                </Interface>
                <Interface id="eth1">
                    <Ipv4 address="10.0.10.2" netmask="255.255.255.252"  />
                    <Ipv6 address="fd00:10:10::1/127" />    
                </Interface>
                <Interface id="eth2">
                    <Ipv4 address="10.0.11.1" netmask="255.255.255.252" />
                    <Ipv6 address="fd00:11:11::0/127" />    
                </Interface>
            </Interfaces>
            <Bgp as="100">
                <Address-family id="Ipv4">
                
                    <Neighbor address="10.0.10.3" remote-as="200" />
                    <Neighbor address="10.0.33.1" remote-as="300" />
                    <Neighbor address="10.0.13.2" remote-as="100" /> 
                    <Network address="100.0.1.0" />
                </Address-family>
                <Address-family id="Ipv6">
                    <Neighbor address="fd00:10:10::2" remote-as="200" />
                    <Neighbor address="fd00:33:33::0" remote-as="300" />
                    <Neighbor address="fd00:13:13::1" remote-as="300" />
                    <Network address="fd00:100:0:100::" remote-as="100" />
                </Address-family>
           </Bgp>
        </Router>
        
        
        <Router name="B" id="200.0.2.1"  >
            <Interfaces>
               <Interface id="eth0">
                    <Ipv4 address="10.0.34.1" netmask="255.255.255.252" />
                    <Ipv6 address="fd00:34:34::0/127" /> 
                </Interface>
                <Interface id="eth1">
                    <Ipv4 address="10.0.10.3" netmask="255.255.255.252" />
                    <Ipv6 address="fd00:10:10::2/127" />
                </Interface>
                <Interface id="eth2">
                    <Ipv4 address="10.0.35.1" netmask="255.255.255.252" />
                    <Ipv6 address="fd00:35:35::0/127" />
                </Interface>
            </Interfaces>   
            <Bgp as="200">
                <Address-family id="Ipv4">
                    <Neighbor address="10.0.10.2" remote-as="100" />
                    <Neighbor address="10.0.35.2" remote-as="300" />
                    <Network address="200.0.2.0" />
                </Address-family>
                <Address-family id="Ipv6">
                    <Neighbor address="fd00:10:10::1" remote-as="100" />
                    <Neighbor address="fd00:35:35::1" remote-as="300" />
                    <Network address="fd00:200:0:200::" />
                </Address-family>   
            </Bgp>  
        </Router>
        
        <Router name="C" id="100.0.4.1">
            <Interfaces>
                <Interface id="eth0">
                    <Ipv4 address="10.0.56.1" netmask="255.255.255.252" />
                    <Ipv6 address="fd00:56:56::0/127" />
                </Interface>
                <Interface id="eth1">
                    <Ipv4 address="10.0.33.1" netmask="255.255.255.252" />
                    <Ipv6 address="fd00:33:33::0/127" />
                </Interface>
                <Interface id="eth2">
                    <Ipv4 address="10.0.35.2" netmask="255.255.255.252" />
                    <Ipv6 address="fd00:35:35::1/127" />
                </Interface>
                
            </Interfaces>
            <Bgp as="300" id="100.0.4.1">
                <Address-family id="Ipv4">
                    <Neighbor address="10.0.11.1" remote-as="100" />
                    <Neighbor address="10.0.35.1" remote-as="200" />
                    <Network address="100.0.4.0" />
                </Address-family>
                <Address-family id="Ipv6">
                    <Neighbor address="fd00:11:11::0" remote-as="100" />
                    <Neighbor address="fd00:35:35::0" remote-as="200" />
                    <Network address="fd00:300:0:400::" />
                </Address-family>   
            </Bgp>
        </Router>
        
     </Devices>
     
                    
 </BGPConfig>
```

This is my NED file:

```
package inet.examples.MonNemo;

import inet.common.misc.ThruputMeteringChannel;
import inet.examples.inet.ipv4hook.MyRouter;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv6.Ipv6FlatNetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.bgp.BgpRouter;
import inet.node.eigrp.EigrpRouter;
import inet.node.ethernet.EthernetSwitch;
import inet.node.ipv6.Router6;
import inet.node.wireless.AccessPoint;

import inet.physicallayer.wireless.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.canvas.integrated.IntegratedCanvasVisualizer;

import inet.node.bgp.BgpRouter6;
//
// TODO auto-generated type
//

channel LINK_100 extends ThruputMeteringChannel
{
    parameters:
        delay = 50us;
        datarate = 100Mbps;
        displayAsTooltip = true;
        //thruputDisplayFormat = "#N";
}
channel ethernetline extends ned.DatarateChannel
{
    parameters:
        delay = 0.1us;
        datarate = 100Mbps;
}

network MyNetwork_1
{
    parameters:
        

        @display("bgb=1230.944,1091.376");

    submodules:
        visualizer: IntegratedCanvasVisualizer {
            @display("p=1022.13007,661.476;is=s");
        }
        

        configurator6: Ipv6FlatNetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=1022.13007,744.57605;is=s");
        }
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=1022.13007,835.986;is=s");
            //config = xmldoc("IPv6Config.xml");
           // addStaticRoutes = true;
            //addDefaultRoutes = true;
            //addSubnetRoutes = true;
            //optimizeRoutes = true;
        }

        radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {
            @display("p=1020.468,575.052;is=s");
        }
        A: BgpRouter {
            @display("p=441.58398,308.88;is=s");
            gates:
                ethg[3];
        }

        B: BgpRouter {
            @display("p=609.308,311.136;is=s");
            gates:
                ethg[3];
        }
        C: BgpRouter {
            @display("p=516.708,438.924;is=s");
            gates:
                ethg[3];
        }

        BR_1: Router6 {
            @display("p=253.724,296.32;is=s");

        }
        BR_2: Router6 {
            @display("p=761.172,311.136;is=s");

        }
        BR_3: Router6 {
            @display("p=531.524,574.12;is=s");

        }


    connections:
        A.ethg[1] <--> LINK_100 <--> B.ethg[1];
        B.ethg[2] <--> LINK_100 <--> C.ethg[2];
        A.ethg[2] <--> LINK_100 <--> C.ethg[1];

        A.ethg[0] <--> LINK_100 <--> BR_1.ethg++;
       

        B.ethg[0] <--> LINK_100 <--> BR_2.ethg++;
       

        C.ethg[0] <--> LINK_100 <--> BR_3.ethg++;
        
}
```

This is my `omnetpp.ini`:

```
[General]
#network = MyNetwork
#record-eventlog = true

num-rngs = 3
seed-set = 1
**.gen[*].rng-0 = 1
**.mobility.rng-0 = 2

debug-on-errors = false

cmdenv-express-mode = true

**.vector-recording = false

**.debug = true
**.coreDebug = false


# ip settings
**.ip.procDelay = 1us
# NIC configuration
**.eth[*].queue.typename = "EthernetQosQueue"
**.eth[*].queue.dataQueue.typename = "DropTailQueue"
**.eth[*].queue.dataQueue.frameCapacity = 100

#tcp settings
**.tcp.mss = 1024
**.tcp.advertisedWindow = 14336
#**.tcp.sendQueueClass = "TCPMsgBasedSendQueue"
#**.tcp.receiveQueueClass = "TCPMsgBasedRcvQueue"
**.tcp.tcpAlgorithmClass = "TcpReno"
**.tcp.recordStats = false
[Config One]
network = MyNetwork_1

#*.visualizer.routingTableVisualizer.displayRoutingTables = true
# bgp settings

**.bgpConfig = xmldoc("BGPConfig.xml")
```

This is my network:
[image]

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77136208/edit) the question and add your NED file as well as `omnetpp.ini`?

Comment: No one for help? is the issue related to addressing?

Comment: We are willing to help you, but we need [mcve] to reproduce your error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've included a link at the end of all code sections to show you how my network looks like.

Comment: the only thing is that I  would like to know how this address appeared, knowing I didn’t set it up.

Answer (score 0):

The addresses of hosts in the network are assigned by `configurator` which is an instance of `Ipv4NetworkConfigurator`. You had left default settings of `configurator`, so it assigned addresses from `10.x.x.x` - take a look at `/inet4.4/src/inet/networklayer/configurator/ipv4/Ipv4NetworkConfigurator.ned`:

```
xml config = default(xml("<config><interface hosts='**' address='10.x.x.x' netmask='255.x.x.x'/></config>"));
```

I suggest setting in your NED:

```
configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
   @display("p=1022.13007,835.986;is=s");
   config = xmldoc("IPv4Config.xml");
   addStaticRoutes = false;
   addDefaultRoutes = false;
   addSubnetRoutes = false;
```

and preparing `IPv4Config.xml` with own addresses of interfaces.

Comment: If the answer does not resolve your issue, write a comment instead of editing the answer.

Comment: In BGP-XML configuration, there are BGP addresses, in IPvConfig.xml, I added BRs addresses. At simulation, I got this message : "<!> BGP Error:  No AS configuration for Router ID: <unspec> -- in module (inet::bgp::Bgp) MyNetwork_1.A.bgp (id=76), during network initialization"

Comment: I suggest creating a new question that will contain [mcve].